# How do I access a Windows 10 Storage Spaces from another Windows 10 install?

Tags: windows-10, raid, storage, software-raid, storage-spaces

> **BACKGROUND**

So a while ago (maybe 3 weeks ago) I decided to divide my NVMe in half to duel boot Windows and Linux. In the process I somehow deleted my Windows boot partitions or something. I honestly have no idea what happened but Windows is not a bios boot option anymore. I want to remove Windows 10 from my NVMe (or fix it an move it to a HDD) but there is a Storage Spaces pool with two of my 1TB drives. On there are some videos and files that I do not want to lose. The problem is, I can't access it from Linux and I don't want to delete or migrate the Windows 10 installation that created it before I can get the files off.

> **WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

I have both a Windows installation media to boot into and an old laptop HDD with Window 10 on it.
I have tried using the installation media to fix my Windows 10 on my NVMe to no avail. I have tried the bcdboot stuff and the /fixboot and /fixmbr also to no avail. They all return their collection of errors. I have thus almost given up on fixing it (Unless someone here helps me figure that out) and just want to get the data off those drives now.
I have booted into the HDD to see if the laptop Windows 10 would detect and mount the Storage Space pool but the laptop Windows 10 doesn't even detect the drives. The only place they show up is Device Manager. [This is what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNknR.png). As far as I can tell my laptop Windows 10 is updated (The most common issue I saw) but still no dice.

> **INFO**

According to the properties tab in there, the status is all fine. It's saying it's connected and functioning. Below is what Linux says about the connected drives. sda and sdc are the storage space drives, sdb is my attempt at installing a new Windows 10 on a free HDD (it error out at the end), and nvme0n1p is my main NVMe which I have the Linux partitions bold and the old Windows install italic. The rest are mostly my attempts in the installation media to create a new EFI. I didn't really know what I was doing and was just gluing together online tutorials...

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk model: INTEL SSDPEKNW010T8                     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: DB39829D-3C32-11EC-BA97-5CF3708894B3

Device              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048     104447     102400    50M Microsoft basic data
*/dev/nvme0n1p2     104448 1013065727 1012961280   483G Microsoft basic data*
/dev/nvme0n1p3 1013065728 1013475327     409600   200M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p4 1013475328 1013737471     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p5 1013737472 1013942271     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p6 1013942272 1014147071     204800   100M EFI System
**/dev/nvme0n1p7 1014908928 1998358526  983449599 468.9G Linux filesystem**
**/dev/nvme0n1p8 1998358528 1999382526    1023999   500M EFI System**
/dev/nvme0n1p9 1999382528 2000404479    1021952   499M Windows recovery environm


Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: Hitachi HDS72101
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7E9C3F2F-421E-11EB-BA75-5CF3708894B3

Device      Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1    2048     264191     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2  264192 1953523711 1953259520 931.4G Microsoft Storage Spaces


Disk /dev/sdb: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: Hitachi HDS72101
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0897C9BD-80E3-488A-925F-6774096DC888

Device      Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1    2048     206847     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sdb2  206848     239615      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb3  239616 1953523711 1953284096 931.4G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sdc: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: Hitachi HDS72101
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7E9C3F37-421E-11EB-BA75-5CF3708894B3

Device      Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdc1    2048     264191     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdc2  264192 1953523711 1953259520 931.4G Microsoft Storage Spaces
```

Here are also screenshots of each drive in GParted for more info:

- [nvme0n1p (my main drive)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIGZT.png)
- [sda (Storage Space Drive)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4Abv.png)
- [sdb (Failed Windows Install)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur7qG.png)
- [sdc (Storage Space Drive)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJ3OS.png)

In conclusion. I did try to do this myself, I made a mess of my nvme and popped partitions all over the place, dug out an ancient laptop HDD, turned an SDCard into a bootable installation media, and even asked the kind people over at Unix & Linux for help trying to access the drives from the Linux side. It has been about 2 weeks of scouring the internet, having half of it fly over my head, and trying to other half. I think it's about time I finally asked for help with the Windows side.

Comment: You need to the owner of the space so you need  to take ownership of the space.

Comment: You "should be" able to mount that partition on the linux side and copy your files off.  I don't see anything in your post or visually about actually mounting that partition so you can get to the files.  It is the Linux equivalent of mapping a drive letter (if you already know this, no offense). Otherwise, you will need to do as @John says and take ownership of the files from a windows boot and copy them off that way.  Either way, your files are probably still there. :)

Comment: First of all thank you for your replies! Unfortunately I can't see the files at all or even the drives on the windows side. The only place they show is in the device manager. I'm not sure how to take ownership of the file if windows isn't showing any files. The drives don't even show in diskpart on the windows side. As for mounting them on Linux, that was something the people at Unix & Linux (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/676845/500656) suggested. I tried mounting as an NTFS but it said it couldn't identify it as NTFS. Is there a way to mount these drives in win10 without diskpart?

Comment: @CharlesBurns Thank you for your input. I still haven't managed to fix this and honestly I'm not sure if I ever will. I have since removed the drives from my PC, backed up my windows install, and shelfed it. I may try again some day. Until then, it appears I will have lost the battle against Microsoft. C'est la vie!